# Replace existing custom fields from global.mpt

Tags: vba, ms-project

We run a lot of project files and want to update / replace existing custom fields with new lookups and formulas that are stored in our global file when I open the file.

I've come up with the following code but the problem is that it doesn't append the ".mpp" file type if the file has been saved. I've also tried "ActiveProject.FullName", however this returns runtime 1101 error.

I don't want to hardcode the filename as this would by a nightmare to manage.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

thanks in advance

```
Sub DeleteUpdateFields()

OrganizerDeleteItem pjFields, FileName:=ActiveProject.Name, Name:="Test (Text19)"
OrganizerMoveItem pjFields, FileName:="Global.MPT", ToFileName:=ActiveProject.Name, Name:="Test (Text19)"

End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe,
You don't specify if the extension (.mpp) is always missing or just for some files but here's a bit of code that will first test for the extension and then add it if it's missing.

The reason you got the runtime error is because ActiveProject.FullName includes the path which is not a valid argument in this instance.

I assume your code runs as an Open Event in each file rather then you having to initiate the macro for each file. If not, let us know.

```
Option Compare Text
Sub DeleteUpdateFields()
Dim FNam As String
FNam = ActiveProject.Name
If InStr(1, ActiveProject.Name, ".mpp") = 0 Then
    FNam = ActiveProject.Name & ".mpp"
End If
OrganizerDeleteItem pjFields, FileName:=FNam, Name:="Test (Text19)"
OrganizerMoveItem pjFields, FileName:="Global.MPT", ToFileName:=FNam,     Name:="Test (Text19)"

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.
John

Comment: Actually, the path is a valid argument, it just needs to end with .mpp

Comment: Kenny, you are absolutely right, the full path is a valid argument. I got ahead of myself and didn't actually test the code before posting. Thanks for correcting my error. John

Comment: One caveat, if the project the the field is being deleted from is open off of Project Server (PWA), having the “.mpp” at the end will cause an error. As long as you aren’t dealing with those kinds of projects, should be all good